# ¿Cómo ajustar contenido de DIV en diferentes resoluciones de pantalla?

Tags: html, css, materialize

Mi problema es que tengo una barra de navegación que tiene enlaces:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando hago la pagina mas pequeña, pasa esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero logras es que se acomoden en filas, y que el div se ajuste para envolverlos, este es mi `html`:

```
<div class='hide-on-small-only contenedor'>
<nav class='menu green darken-3 fixed-bar'>
<ul id='nav-mobile' class='col s5 m5 l5 right hide-on-med-and-down'>
<li><a id='guardar'>Guardar (F1)</a></li>
<li><a id='eliminar'>Eliminar (F2)</a></li>
<li><a id='cancelar'>Cancelar (F3)</a></li>
<li><a id='subir_foto'>Subir Foto (F4)</a></li>
<li><a id='descargar_foto'>Descargar Foto (F5)</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

y este mi `css`:

```
.contenedor {
    width: 50%;
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.contenedor p {
    margin-bottom:40px;
}

header nav {
    background:#3498db;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

header nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

header nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding:20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1000;
    top:0;
    max-width:1000px;
    width:50%;
    box-shadow:0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
header nav ul li a:hover {
    background:#2980b9;
}
```

Estoy usando `Materialize`, así que si hay alguna solución mas rápida usando el `Framework`, es bienvenida. Espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias-

Answer (score 2):

Ya has intentado usar **`mediaqueries`**?

Agregando por ejemplo este código al final de tu demo, el menú se coloca al 100% de la pantalla:

```
@media (max-width: 840px){
  .menu{
    width: 100%;
  }

  #nav-mobile{
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Y por defecto, deja el **`#nav-mobile`** como otro `flex`.

```
#nav-mobile {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Así (Tienes que probar ampliando y reduciendo la ventana):

```css
.contenedor {
    width: 50%;
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.contenedor p {
    margin-bottom:40px;
}

header nav {
    background:#3498db;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#nav-mobile {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav-mobile  li {
}

#nav-mobile  a {
    display: block;
    padding:5px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1000;
    top:0;
    max-width:1000px;
    width:50%;
    box-shadow:0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: green;
}
header nav ul li a:hover {
    background:#2980b9;
}

@media (max-width: 840px){
  .menu{
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  #nav-mobile{
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='hide-on-small-only contenedor'>
  <nav class='menu green darken-3 fixed-bar'>
    <ul id='nav-mobile' class='col s5 m5 l5 right hide-on-med-and-down'>
      <li><a id='guardar'>Guardar (F1)</a></li>
      <li><a id='eliminar'>Eliminar (F2)</a></li>
      <li><a id='cancelar'>Cancelar (F3)</a></li>
      <li><a id='subir_foto'>Subir Foto (F4)</a></li>
      <li><a id='descargar_foto'>Descargar Foto (F5)</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```